# Is there "transaction log" on datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I want to check history of datastore operation.
But, I cannot found it on logging/datastore console/stackdriver.

Is there "transaction log" about datastore?
Should I insert log manually to webapp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, datastore transactions are not logged.

If you so desire you'd have to create such logs yourself. See [Using Stackdriver logging in App Engine apps](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/logging).